# Show that $H(x) := |x|^{-1} u(x/|x|^2) $ is harmonic if $u$ is harmonic

Tags: harmonic-functions

I have a "simple" question but I'm not able to solve it.

> Suppose that $u$ is a harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Prove that the function $H(x) := |x|^{-1} u(x/|x|^2) $ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus\{0\}$

I tried brute force evaluating $\Delta H$ but even there I had some problems.. Any hint or partial solution is welcomed.

Comment: What problems were you facing when evaluating $ \Delta H$?

Comment: For example, evaluating $\partial_{x_1} H$ I can't figure out what is $\partial_{x_1} u(x/|x|^2)$. (I used $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$)

Comment: You know I imagine that $\partial_x u(x/|x|^2)$ is an abuse of notation. The $x$ in $\partial_x$ represent a single coordinate while it is a vector in $\vert x \vert$?

Comment: Yes, because of that I called (for example) the coordinate system $x_1,x_2,x_3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt:

$$D_iH
= \frac{x_i}{|x|^3}u+\frac 1{|x|}\sum_{j=1}^3D_ju\cdot\left(\frac
{\delta_{ij}}{|x|^2}-\frac{2x_ix_j}{|x|^4}\right)
$$
and
\begin{align*}
D_{ii}H
& = \left(\frac{1}{|x|^3}-\frac{3x_i^2}{|x|^5}\right)u +\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}\sum_{j=1}^3D_ju\cdot\left(\frac
{\delta_{ij}}{|x|^2}-\frac{2x_ix_j}{|x|^4}\right)\\
& -\frac{x_i}{|x|^3}\sum_{j=1}^3D_ju\cdot\left(\frac
{\delta_{ij}}{|x|^2}-\frac{2x_ix_j}{|x|^4}\right)\\
& + \frac 1{|x|}\cdot\frac{D_{ii} u}{|x|^2}+\frac 1{|x|}\frac{2D_iu\cdot x_i}{|x|^4}\\
&-\frac{1}{|x|}\sum_{j=1}^3\left(D_{ij}u\cdot \frac{2x_ix_j\delta_{ij}}{|x|^4} + D_j u\cdot \left(\frac{2x_j}{|x|^4} + \frac{2x_i\delta_{ij}}{|x|^4} + \frac{4x_i^2x_j}{|x|^6} \right)\right)\\
& = \frac{1}{|x|^3}-\frac{3x_i^2}{|x|^5} + \frac{D_{ii}}{|x|^3}.
\end{align*}
Using the harmonicity of $u,$ we get $\Delta H=0$ if I don't miscalculate anything (when cancelling some terms).