# Show that $H(x):=\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}u(\frac{x}{|x|^2})$ is harmonic if $u$ is harmonic

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

(This is the $n$-dimensional analogue of the 3D case: [Show that $H(x) := |x|^{-1} u(x/|x|^2) $ is harmonic if $u$ is harmonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3975097/show-that-hx-x-1-ux-x2-is-harmonic-if-u-is-harmonic))

> Suppose that $u$ is a harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
> Prove that the function $\displaystyle H(x):=\frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}u\left(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\right)$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$.

I tried to compute $\Delta H$ directly by following the brute force method in the linked question, but it gets tedious very soon. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a more elegant way?

I am thinking to use the converse of mean value property. So far I have worked out (probably) that

- Under the mapping $f: x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|^2}$, 
   a circle with radius $r$ centered at $x_0$ would be mapped to a circle with radius $R=\frac{2r}{|x_0|^2-r^2}$ centered at $y_0=\frac{x_0}{|x_0|^2-r^2}$.
- $f = f^{-1}$
- Its Jacobian is $|Jf|=|x|^{2n}$.

I am stuck after doing change of variables in the integral $\displaystyle\frac{1}{|B_R(y_0)|}\int_{B_R(y_0)} H(y)dy$ , since the terms do not magically cancel out as wished, and expressing $|B_R(y_0)|$ in terms of the corresponding $|B_r(x_0)|$ also yields a mess.

I really appreciate any help. Other methods (or more efficient brute force) are also greatly welcomed.

Comment: Solution is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4097778/u-is-harmonic-prove-that-vx-frac1xn-2-cdot-u-left-fracxx2/4098093#4098093

Comment: @Svyatoslav thank you for adding your comment, I knew I saw it recently but could not find it again

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you very much, the solution is so systematic!

Comment: Also, would anyone advise on how to handle this question now? Should I flag it as a duplicate, or edit it to specifically asking for a solution using mean value property instead? In any case, thank you everyone for the inputs so far!

Comment: I think the question on using MVP is interesting. If you prefer it to be closed as a dupe, I can vote to close and then you (as the post author) will have a button to have it closed

Comment: After reading your post again, I remembered the "method of image charge". Some googling led me to the Wikipedia page for the [Kelvin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_transform) and then consequently [this post from 7+ years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601384/show-that-the-kelvin-transform-is-harmonic). Even there the calculation is explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $|x|^{2-n}$ is harmonic, in the following calculations
we will let $\phi(x):=|x|^{2-n}$ and use the Einstein summation rule
to simplify our procedure.

Since $\bar{u}(x) = \phi(x) u\bigl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\bigr)$, we calculate to get
$$\bar{u}_{x_i}(x) = \phi_{x_i}(x) u\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr)
    + \phi(x) u_{x_j} \biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i}.$$
Differentiate again with respect to $x_i$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
    \bar{u}_{x_ix_i}
    & = \phi_{x_ix_i} u\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr)
        + 2\phi_{x_i} u_{x_j}\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr) \biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i} \\
    & \quad + \phi(x) u_{x_jx_k}\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr) \biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i}
          \biggl(\frac{x_k}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i}
        + \phi(x) u_{x_j} \biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr) \biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_ix_i}.
  \end{align*}
So
$$\Delta \bar{u}(x) = 0 + A + B + C.$$
Next we calculate $A$, $B$ and $C$ seperately. Since
$$\biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i} = \frac{\delta_{ij} |x|^2 - 2x_ix_j}{|x|^4}.$$
It follows that
$$x_i \biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i} = -\frac{x_j}{|x|^2},$$
and
$$\biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i} \biggl(\frac{x_k}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i}
    = \frac{\delta_{jk}}{|x|^4}.$$
(note: the above equality is just the same as
$D_x\bar{x}(D_x\bar{x})^T = |\bar{x}|^4I$)
Therefore, by combining $\phi_{x_i}(x) = (2-n)|x|^{-n}x_i$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
A & = 2(2-n)|x|^{-n} x_i \biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_i} u_{x_j}\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr) \\
  & = 2(2-n)|x|^{-n} \biggl(-\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr) u_{x_j}\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr) \\
  & = 2(n-2)|x|^{-n-2} x\cdot Du\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr).
  \end{align*}
$$B = \phi(x) u_{x_jx_k}\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr) \frac{\delta_{jk}}{|x|^4}
= |x|^{-n-2} \Delta u\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr).$$
Finally we have to calculate $\Bigl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\Bigr)_{x_ix_i}$ (be careful to this term!),
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac{x_j}{|x|^2}\biggr)_{x_ix_i}
& = \biggl(\frac{\delta_{ij} |x|^2 - 2x_ix_j}{|x|^4}\biggr)_{x_i} \\
& = \frac{\bigl(2\delta_{ij}x_i - 2(\delta_{ij}+1)x_j\bigr) |x|^4
          -(\delta_{ij}|x|^2 - 2x_ix_j)4|x|^2x_i}{|x|^8} \\
& = \frac{(-2n+4)x_j}{|x|^4}.
  \end{align*}
So
$$C = \phi(x) u_{x_j}\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr) \frac{(-2n+4)x_j}{|x|^4}
= (-2n+4)|x|^{-n-2} x\cdot Du\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr).$$

Combining all these results, we conclude that
$$\Delta\bar{u}(x) = A + B + C = B = |x|^{-n-2} \Delta u\biggl(\frac{x}{|x|^2}\biggr).$$

Answer (score -1):

I'm putting this in as an answer as it's too long for a comment.

---

This will definitely be computation-heavy, but here are some formulas that could help. Note that the bolded nabla is understood to be the general tensor gradient, also known as the covariant derivative.

The gradient has a chain rule for $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, $\mathrm{v}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$
$$\nabla(\varphi\circ \mathrm{v})=(\nabla\varphi\circ\mathrm{v})~\boldsymbol\nabla\mathrm{v}$$
The divergence has one as well, for $\mathrm{w}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$\nabla\boldsymbol{\cdot}(\mathrm{v}\circ\mathrm{w})=\operatorname{tr}\big((\boldsymbol\nabla\mathrm{v}\circ\mathrm{w})\boldsymbol\nabla\mathrm w\big)$$

Comment: Yours is only 49 chars too long. With minor changes, look: This will definitely be computation-heavy, but here are some formulas that could help. Note that the bolded nabla is understood to be the general tensor gradient, also known as the covariant derivative. 

The gradient has a chain rule for $\phi:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, ${v}:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ 
$$\nabla(\phi\circ {v})=(\nabla\phi\circ{v})~\boldsymbol\nabla{v}$$
The divergence has one as well, for ${w}:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$:
$$\nabla\boldsymbol{\cdot}({v}\circ{w})=\operatorname{tr}((\boldsymbol\nabla{v}\circ{w})\boldsymbol\nabla w)$$

Comment: No words removed; you could have left 2 comments anyway. `This will definitely be computation-heavy, but here are some formulas that could help. Note that the bolded nabla is understood to be the general tensor gradient, also known as the covariant derivative. 

The gradient has a chain rule for $\phi:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, ${v}:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ 
$$\nabla(\phi\circ {v})=(\nabla\phi\circ{v})~\boldsymbol\nabla{v}$$
The divergence has one as well, for ${w}:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$:
$$\nabla\boldsymbol{\cdot}({v}\circ{w})=\operatorname{tr}((\boldsymbol\nabla{v}\circ{w})\boldsymbol\nabla w)$$`

Comment: Thanks for the input I guess Calvin?

Comment: It seems my comments are not appreciated; sorry. This Answer is just not "too long for a comment", and I feel unanswered questions that can reasonably expect full answers should not have non-answers as the only Answer.